# Magento backorder note in shopping cart

Tags: magento, fonts, notifications, cart

How to change the color of this note in the shopping cart?
I couldn't find it in the main css file.
The font is a light grey per default and easily not seen buy buyers.
I would like to change that but can't find the right file to do so.

Comment: Take a look at how to inspect element and find out the class name https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use chrome, right click on the element (exp text or input) then choose "Inspect Element", and you will find css url path

Comment: Thanks for your answers. A friend recommended chrome or firebug for firefox to me. I used the latter and found the css path easily.
A very helpful tool.